# android - get the current location of lon and lat and put into a GeoPoint?

Tags: android

> Here the following code i have, but there's error. Can someone help?

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude());
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "My Current Location", "My Current Location");
        overlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);

    }
```

Comment: @jeet GeoPoint requires integer but the loc.getLatitude() returns a double

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `GeoPoint` stores coordinates in microdegrees, so to convert `Location` to `GeoPoint` you'll use this code:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(loc.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int)(loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm using to following to create GeoPoints with degrees and/or microdegrees:

```
/**
 * Create a {@link GeoPoint} from float values.
 * @param lat Latitude as float
 * @param lng Longitude as float
 * @return {@link GeoPoint}
 */
public static GeoPoint createGeoPoint( double lat, double lng) {
        return new GeoPoint(degreesToMicrodegrees(lat), degreesToMicrodegrees(lng));
}

/** Convert a float point degree value into a micro deree value */
public static int degreesToMicrodegrees( double deg ) {
        return (int)(deg * 1E6);
}
```

This should help you.

So your code would be like:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GeoPoint point = createGeoPoint(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude());
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "My Current Location", "My Current Location");
    overlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(overlay);

}
```

Comment: Take into account that it was hand written :D

Answer (score 0):

```
GeoPoint pointRabat = new GeoPoint(microDegres(latitude),
                microDegres(longitude));
        mapController.setCenter(pointRabat);


    private int microDegres(double value) {
        return (int) (value * 1000000);
    }
```